# set mutt default Maildir folder

Tags: maildir, mutt

I have recently set up a mail server running postfix as the MTA, and dovecot as the imap/pop3 daemon.  Originally, and by default on Debian, it was using the mbox format.  For reliability reasons, I decided that it would be best to use the Maildir format instead.  Getting help from a friend, I successfully modified the postfix and dovecot servers to use the Maildir format with the mailboxes located in ~/Maildir.

However, mutt is still doing weird things when I try to access my mail using it.  It wants to create a ~/Mail directory, and furthermore wants to look for an mbox in /var/mail/.  There are a few users on the system, and while I know that I can use my .muttrc to solve this problem, how can I fix this problem for all users on my server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

mutt also uses a global muttrc file. Typically it's in `/etc/Muttrc` or `/usr/local/etc/Muttrc` if you compiled it separately from the distro. You can just put the Maildir settings there.

This [mutt & Maildir Mini-HOWTO](http://www.elho.net/mutt/maildir/) should give you an idea of what settings you need to change. Essentially you need to set `folder` and `mbox` and `spoolfile` to all point to `~/Maildir` for everyone, and ensure `mbox_type=Maildir` as well. Then there are a few other options to change the behavior.

Comment: Note: `spoolfile` is the actual delivery ("spool") mailbox, while `folder` is the folder that contains all the user's mailboxes. So typically `spoolfile` would be inside `folder`, not the same. Also, there's no need to mess with `mbox`. Users can set it as they like, or disable moving of mail (`set move=no`), in which case it's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Like most Unix / Linux programs, mutt will also read a system-wide configuration file, `/etc/Muttrc`.

You can put system-wide settings (like where the home mailbox is) there.

Comment: "(like where the home mailbox is)"  Where?

Comment: @bobobobo: There are several options which control this. Read up on options "mbox", "move" and "spoolfile" in mutt's manual ( http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/ ). Then ask a specific question here :-).

Comment: For example, `$HOME/.muttrc` would be one option, which would map to `/home/username/.muttrc` where `username` represents the account used to log into the computer.